# Protocol buffer stream type for socket send

Tags: c++, networking, protocol-buffers

I trying to send length prefixed buffer on socket. I am using protocol buffer. I googled around and I found out that it can be achieved using WriteVarint32 present in CodedOutputStream. But all examples are either using file stream or boost asio. A normal socket send needs a void * as buffer to send over the socket but when done using boost asio I get the following error

> error: invalid cast from type ‘boost::asio::const_buffers_1’ to type ‘void*’

My client side code is

```
Person payload ;
payload.set_log_msg("We are using protobuf");
boost::asio::streambuf b;
std::ostream os(&b);

ZeroCopyOutputStream *raw_output = new OstreamOutputStream(&os);
CodedOutputStream *coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);

coded_output->WriteVarint32(payload.ByteSize());
payload.SerializeToCodedStream(coded_output);
delete coded_output;
delete raw_output;
.
.
.
bytecount=send(hsock, (void *) b.data(), 10,0);
```

Content of my message.proto file is

```
message Person {
  required fixed64 log_time =1;
  required fixed32 log_micro_sec =2;
  required fixed32 sequence_no =3;
  required fixed32 shm_app_id =4;
  required string packet_id =5;
  required string log_level=6;
  required string log_msg=7;

  }
```

Can any one help me in replacing the boost::asio::streambuf with something else so that I can send it on a normal socket send. The function of this client is to send some messages to server. And the server in turn writes them to a log file after doing some formatting.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [boost::asio documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/const_buffer.html)

Accessing Buffer Contents:

```
boost::asio::const_buffer b1 = ...;
std::size_t s1 = boost::asio::buffer_size(b1);
const unsigned char* p1 = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*>(b1);
```

so you can call:

```
bytecount = send(hsock, 
                 boost::asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*>(b.data()),  
                 boost::asio::buffer_size(b.data()), 
                 0);
```

Comment: g++ Client.cpp ../message.pb.o -I../ -I /root/boost_1_41_0/ -lprotobuf
Client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Client.cpp:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘buffer_cast(boost::asio::streambuf&)’
Client.cpp:101: error: no matching function for call to ‘buffer_size(boost::asio::streambuf*)’
/root/boost_1_41_0/boost/asio/buffer.hpp:148: note: candidates are: size_t boost::asio::buffer_size(const boost::asio::mutable_buffer&)
/root/boost_1_41_0/boost/asio/buffer.hpp:318: note:                 size_t boost::asio::buffer_size(const boost::asio::const_buffer&)
getting error

Comment: Actually its oost::asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*>(b.data()), Thanks a lot for the help